# How to inverse this command?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I'm making a voice ranking system on Discord, for now everything is good, but I'm stuck in something.
I made this command, it will let you able to get the Xp amount from a level, and it converts the Xp to time, like:

[image: The command]

The levels system is based on that code:

```js
 module.exports = {
    name: 'lvl',
    execute(message, args) {

      const start = 216000 //From lvl1 to lvl2
      const coe = 125 //Coefficient
      const lvls = 2 //The number of lvls in each stage

      function msToTime(duration) { //ms to time, usage: msToTime(xp + '00'), 1 xp = 0.1 sec
        var milliseconds = parseInt((duration % 1000) / 100),
        seconds = Math.floor((duration / 1000) % 60),
        minutes = Math.floor((duration / (1000 * 60)) % 60),
        hours = Math.floor((duration / (1000 * 60 * 60)));

        hours = (hours < 10) ? "0" + hours : hours;
        minutes = (minutes < 10) ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
        seconds = (seconds < 10) ? "0" + seconds : seconds;

        return hours + "h & " + minutes + "m & " + seconds + "s";
      } 


      function Stage(lvl) { //Get the stage number from a lvl, stages are used to divide lvls
        const a = + lvl - 1    
        const b = Math.floor((a/2) + 1)
        const c = b.toString()
        console.log(c)      
        return c;
      }

      function Percentage(stage) { //Get the lvls inflation percentage, each stage the percentage will be larger
        const a = stage * coe
        const b = a.toString()
        console.log(b)        
        return b;
      }

      function Xp(lvl) { //Get the Xp amount from a lvl
        const a = (Percentage(Stage(lvl)) * (lvl - 1))  
        const b = start + (start * a / 100)
        const c = b.toString()   
        console.log(c)
        return c;
      }

     message.channel.send('Xp: ' + Xp(args[0]) + ', Time: ' + msToTime(Xp(args[0]) + '00')) //Send the Xp amount and the time
  }
};
```

But now, I don't know how to inverse it to get the level from Xp, for example:
You type `.xp 486000`, it will give you `lvl 2`.

So anyone has an idea? ~and thx.

**Edit:** (I removed the stages function)

```js
 module.exports = {
    name: 'lvl',
    execute(message, args) {

      const start = 216000 //From lvl1 to lvl2
      const coe = 65 //Coefficient

      function msToTime(duration) { //ms to time, usage: msToTime(xp + '00'), 1 xp = 0.1 sec
        var milliseconds = parseInt((duration % 1000) / 100),
        seconds = Math.floor((duration / 1000) % 60),
        minutes = Math.floor((duration / (1000 * 60)) % 60),
        hours = Math.floor((duration / (1000 * 60 * 60)));

        hours = (hours < 10) ? "0" + hours : hours;
        minutes = (minutes < 10) ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
        seconds = (seconds < 10) ? "0" + seconds : seconds;

        return hours + "h & " + minutes + "m & " + seconds + "s";
      }     

      function Percentage(lvl) { //Get the lvls inflation percentage
        const a = lvl * coe
        const b = a.toString()
        console.log(b)        
        return b;
      }

      function Xp(lvl) { //Get the Xp amount from a lvl
        const a = (Percentage(lvl) * (lvl - 1))  
        const b = start + (start * a / 100)
        const c = b.toString()   
        console.log(c)
        return c;
      }

     message.channel.send('Xp: ' + Xp(args[0]) + ', Time: ' + msToTime(Xp(args[0]) + '00')) //Send the Xp amount and the time
  }
};
```

Comment: Replace every + with -, every - with +, every * with / and every / with *.

Comment: Is that will work?

Comment: Try and u will know

Comment: nope, its not working. [look](https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/517399972849909760/611244195708928013/unknown.png)

Comment: I don't think it will work, Because of `Math.floor((a/2) + 1)` it is a lossy function, if lvl is even then it's ok, otherwise it will not return correct solution. Do an algebric equation with lvl, xp and the constants (coe and start). You will come to know.

Comment: at the first time i tried an algebraic equation, but the problem was `Math.floor((a/2) + 1)`, you cant inverse it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am attempting this question because I am curious how the algebraic equations will be. So first of all it will NOT work because `Math.floor` is a lossy function. If `lvl` is even the answer is correct otherwise it MAY not be.

So, let's make some algebraic equations.

**stage = st, coe = c, lvl = l, start = s, percentage = p, xp = x**

stage is:

[image]

Percentage is:

[image]

[image]

XP is:

[image]

Solving for Lvl:

[image]

So, you can probably make one JS function out of this, but it will not be correct as I said, `Math.floor` is a lossy function.

You can check it out here:

```
https://www.mathpapa.com/algebra-calculator.html?q=x%3Ds%5Cleft(1%2B%5Cfrac%7B%5Cleft%5B%5Cleft(%5Cfrac%7B%5Cleft(l-1%5Cright)%7D%7B2%7D%2B1%5Cright)c%5Cleft(l-1%5Cright)%5Cright%5D%7D%7B100%7D%5Cright)
```

---

**EDIT:**

Without the `Stage` function, the equation will be:

[image]

Comment: I removed the stages function at all, and I updated the code, can you help me with the new one?

Comment: Edited the answer

Comment: Its incorrect, i tested it, but i found a way to do that

Comment: when the xp is under 197100, the output will be NaN, my equation has this problem too.

Comment: and the min lvl is 0.5, this will happens if c=35

Answer (score 0):

You could define an object with the specific threshold at which a user levels up. Maybe level 1 is 0 seconds, level 2 is 1 hour, level 3 is 5 hours etc, you'd do it like this:

```
let levels = {
    "1": 0
    "2": 1 * 60 * 60 * 1000
    "3": 5 * 60 * 60 * 1000
}
```

Then you could loop through the user's input and check whether it's higher than each level's threshold. Currently your XP is their time in ms. So if they say `10800000` XP (3 hours), a function like this would return that their level is `"2"`:

```
function checkLevel(xp) => {
    let outLevel = "0";
    for (level in levels) {
        let levelXp = levels[level];
        if (xp > levelXp) outLevel = level;
        else break;
    }
    return outLevel;
}
```

If you don't want level XP hardcoded, you could make use of a function that takes in a level and returns the XP required using whatever algorithm you want (ie, your `Xp()` function). You could do something like this:

```
function checkLevel(xp) => {
    let checkLevel = 0;
    let outLevel = 0;
    while (true) {
        let levelXp = levelToXp(checkLevel);
        if (xp > levelXp) outLevel = level;
        else return outLevel.toString();

        checkLevel++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Defining an object will be a solution, but a temp solution. The system should be automatic, and the point of this code is not just for a single command, I need it on my main system.

Comment: I've edited the answer, this third snippet allows level XP to be calculated on the fly.

Comment: I cant understand how it works, but for now i think that the best way to do it is making an algebraic equation.

Answer (score 0):

**This is it:**

```js
function Lvl(xp) { //Get the lvl from Xp
  const a = ((start*coe) + Math.sqrt((start*coe)*((start*coe)-(400*start)+(400*xp)))) / (2*start*coe)
  const b = a.toString()
  console.log(a)
  return b;
}
```